# Is there any relation between single crystal elastic constants and plastic deformation?

Tags: mathematical-physics, material-science

The elastic constants are the tensor coefficient in Hook's Law. Which are valued only in elastic region.But, we are using elastic constants to find the hardness.The hardness is the measure of the resistance to plastic deformation.Then what is the relation between the single crystal elastic constants and plastic deformation?